# MySQL selct multiple column from multiple tables with no link

Tags: mysql, sql

Table1

| id | hour | date | tableValue1 | tableValue2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2020-05-29 | 123 | 145 |
| 2 | 2 | 2020-05-29 | 1500 | 3400 |

Table2:

| id | hour | date | tableValue3 | tableValue4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-05-29 | 4545 | 3697 |
| 2 | 3 | 2020-05-29 | 5698 | 2896 |

Table3:

| id | hour | date | tableValue5 | tableValue6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2020-05-29 | 7841 | 5879 |
| 2 | 1 | 2020-05-29 | 1485 | 3987 |

I want to select multiple columns from different tables with one query.

Expected Output:

| hour | tableValue1 | tableValue3 | tableValue5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 4545 | 1485 |
| 2 | 1500 | 0 | 7841 |
| 3 | 123 | 5698 | 0 |

I've tried this query without success:

```
SELECT hour , tableValue1 WHERE date = "2020-05-29" AND hour BETWEEN 0 AND 10 FROM table1 
UNION ALL
SELECT hour , tableValue3 WHERE date = "2020-05-29" AND hour BETWEEN 0 AND 10 FROM table2 
UNION ALL
SELECT hour , tableValue5 WHERE date = "2020-05-29" AND hour BETWEEN 10 AND 10 FROM table3
```

I'm getting instead the following:

| hour | tableValue1 |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 123 |
| 2 | 1500 |
| 1 | 4545 |
| 3 | 5698 |
| 2 | 5879 |
| 1 | 3987 |

The columns tables have in common are hour and date, do I need to redesign database structure to link the tables, so that I can use `JOIN` command, but how? Or is there a sql command to select multiple column from multiple  tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in your code:

- your `WHERE` clause should be found after the `FROM` clause in your subqueries
- you want different columns, but you associate only one column for each of your table: if you want three columns, each of your subqueries should return three columns
- your rows are not ordered because you're missing an ORDER BY clause at the end of your code.
- your rows are not aggregated to remove the zeroes in excess: in that case it is sufficient to apply a `MAX` aggregation function for each relevant field, partitioning on the "*hour*" field

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT hour, 
           tableValue1, 
           0 AS tableValue3, 
           0 AS tableValue5 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE date = "2020-05-29" AND hour BETWEEN 0 AND 10

    UNION ALL

    SELECT hour, 
           0 AS tableValue1, 
           tableValue3, 
           0 AS tableValue5 
    FROM table2
    WHERE date = "2020-05-29" AND hour BETWEEN 0 AND 10

    UNION ALL

    SELECT hour, 
           0 AS tableValue1, 
           0 AS tableValue3, 
           tableValue5 
    FROM table3
    WHERE date = "2020-05-29" AND hour BETWEEN 0 AND 10

    ORDER BY hour
)
SELECT hour,
       MAX(tableValue1) AS tableValue1,
       MAX(tableValue3) AS tableValue3,
       MAX(tableValue5) AS tableValue5
FROM cte
GROUP BY hour
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sfx3TYSAGfNnHbZHc7Q2H4/2).

Comment: thanks @lemon for your feedback, i try your code and it's works good but the thing is when  columns from different tables have value for the same  the `hour` , hour can get duplicated multiple times , please check the  [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iCkGbXo4R3YSwDC34ZTpwK/0) to have a clear understanding, is there a way to merge those duplicated row into one ?

Comment: If you want to aggregate the identical rows, you can use `UNION` in place of `UNION ALL`, though how would you aggregate rows that have zeros and non-zero values for the same field? Would you keep the minimum/maximum value? Can you share the sample output with respect to your link?

Comment: in my case aggregated rows that have zeros and  non-zero values is most convenient thing to do, at the end all records must have one unique hour , i updated my post so you can see the expected  output

Comment: I've updated the answer accordingly. Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You must introduce empty columns in first query

```
SELECT hour , tableValue1, 0 tableValue3, 0 tableValue5 FROM table1 WHERE date = "2020-05-29" AND hour BETWEEN 0 AND 10  
UNION ALL
SELECT hour , 0, tableValue3, 0  FROM table2 WHERE date = "2020-05-29" AND hour BETWEEN 0 AND 10
UNION ALL
SELECT hour , 0,0 tableValue5 FROM table3 WHERE date = "2020-05-29" AND hour BETWEEN 10 AND 10
```